# Python sqlite copy table from one database to another

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I'm using python 2.7 with the builtin sqlite3 module on Windows XP.  The code looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sqlite3
import sys

def open_db(nam):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sys.argv[1])
    # Let rows returned be of dict/tuple type
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    print "Openned database %s as %r" % (nam, conn)
    return conn

def copy_table(table, src, dest):
    print "Copying %s %s => %s" % (table, src, dest)
    sc = src.execute('SELECT * FROM %s' % table)
    ins = None
    dc = dest.cursor()
    for row in sc.fetchall():
        if not ins:
            cols = tuple([k for k in row.keys() if k != 'id'])
            ins = 'INSERT OR REPLACE INTO %s %s VALUES (%s)' % (table, cols,
                                                     ','.join(['?'] * len(cols)))
            print 'INSERT stmt = ' + ins
        c = [row[c] for c in cols]
        dc.execute(ins, c)

    dest.commit()

src_conn  = open_db(sys.argv[1])
dest_conn = open_db(sys.argv[2])

copy_table('audit', src_conn, dest_conn)
```

When I run this with `db_copy.py src.db dest.db` the source database was doubled.  So I set the source file attribute to readonly.  I now get:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database
```

It seems somewhere the source and destination database connections are mixed?  I've been debugging this for hours without finding the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ignoring the `nam` parameter and using `sys.argv[1]` for all calls to `open_db()`:

```
def open_db(nam):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sys.argv[1])
```

This opens the first named database *twice*, as both `src_conn` and `dest_conn`. Use `nam` instead:

```
def open_db(nam):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(nam)
```